# Problem with slowing down ball in pong game

Tags: python, pygame, pong

I've been making pong with pygame and I got the ball to bounce around the screen and on the paddles. However, the speed is too high and I want to decrease it. This is what the code looks like for the Ball object:

```
import pygame as pg
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)


class Ball(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, width, height, radius):
        super().__init__()

        self.x_vel = 1
        self.y_vel = 1
        self.image = pg.Surface([width * 2, height * 2])
        self.image.fill(BLACK)
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)

        pg.draw.circle(self.image, color, center=[width, height], radius=radius)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update_ball(self):
        self.rect.x += self.x_vel
        self.rect.y += self.y_vel
```

If I try to set the velocity as a float, it stops the ball completely. Can someone help me?

Comment: may be  that rect.x  and rect.y  are  forced to be integer . So if you add 0.4  to rect.x for example ,  it remains the same .   Try to debug rect.x and rect.y after the increment .

Comment: yeah I figured... I'll do what Rabbid76 said. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) to control the frames per second and thus the game speed.

The method [`tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) of a [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) object, delays the game in that way, that every iteration of the loop consumes the same period of time. See [`pygame.time.Clock.tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick):

> This method should be called once per frame.

That means that the loop:

> ```py
> clock = pygame.time.Clock()
> run = True
> while run:
>    clock.tick(100)
> ```

runs 100 times per second.

---

Since [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) is supposed to represent an area on the screen, a `pygame.Rect` object can only store integral data.

> The coordinates for Rect objects are all integers. [...]

The fraction part of the coordinates gets lost when the movement of the object is assigned to the *Rect* object.

If you want to store object positions with floating point accuracy, you have to store the location of the object in separate variables respectively attributes and to synchronize the `pygame.Rect` object. [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) the coordinates and assign it to the location of the rectangle:

```py
class Ball(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, width, height, radius):
        # [...]

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = self.rect.x
        self.y = self.rect.y

    def update_ball(self):
        self.x += self.x_vel
        self.y += self.y_vel
        self.rect.x = round(self.x)
        self.rect.y = round(self.y)
```